# How can I utilize dask's dataframe.read_csv with a google storage globstring while using different skiprows values for each file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have folders in a google bucket that contain CSVs that I'm trying to read into `dask.dataframe`s in order to do parallel normalization on the files. For example: Some of those dataframes may be missing a column that the rest of them have, so I want to insert the missing column into each dataframe that's missing it.

## My problem

When using a globstring, such as `ddfs = ddf.read_csv(f"gs://bucket/{folder}/*.csv")` I will expectedly receive `pandas.errors.ParserErrors` because not only are some of the files' headers missing, some files' header row may not begin on the first row. I can loop through the directory and analyze each file prior to using the globstring with `dask.dataframe`. Below is the logic I would use in that case:

```py
import pandas as pd
file_analysis = dict()
for filepath in files:
    skiprows = None
    while True:
        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(filepath, nrows=nrows, skiprows=skiprows)
            break
        except pd.errors.ParserError as e:
            try:
                start_row_index = re.findall(r"Expected \d+ fields in line (\d+), saw \d+", str(e))[0]
                skiprows = int(start_row_index) - 1
            except IndexError:
                print("Could not locate start_row_index in pandas ParserError message")
                continue
    headers = df.columns.values.tolist()  # noqa
    skiprows = skiprows + 1 if skiprows else 1
    # store dictionary of pandas params that correspond to each file for `.read_csv()` calls
    file_analysis[filepath] = dict(skiprows=skiprows, names=headers, dtype=dict.fromkeys(headers, str))
```

But, this would increase the execution time especially when some directories have thousands of files. And even then, I'm not sure how I would pass the dictionary values to `dask`'s `dataframe.read_csv`

## My question

Is there a way for me to pass a function to `dask.dataframe.read_csv` that would allow for dynamic `skiprows` and maybe also dynamic `columns` for each CSV files in the google bucket folder of the globstring provided to the function?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible to do it via `dd.read_csv`, but you can construct a `dask.dataframe` by using `.from_delayed`, where each delayed is a wrapper around a function that normalizes the csv files and returns a pandas dataframe.

Note that `from_delayed` will expect consistent column names and dtypes, so this is something that should be handled inside the function.